# passing props into the React with typescript component conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, components, react-typescript

```js
//This component is as same as index.js in react
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Card from "./components/Cards/Card";
import ItemCard from "./components/Cards/ItemCard/ItemCard";

const OrderTracking: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <ItemCard doesBadge={true} titleCard={'Square Card'} btnText={'Details'} progressPercentage={'30%'} progressStepName={'ha'} isReady={false} />
        </Card>
    )
};
export default OrderTracking;

if (document.getElementById("order-tracking")) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <OrderTracking/>,

        document.getElementById("order-tracking")
    );
}

//my Card component
import * as React from 'react';
import CardClasses from './Card.module.css';

interface CartProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const Card: React.FC<CartProps> = props => {

    return (
        <div className={CardClasses.card__container}
        >
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;




//Item card component
import React from 'react';
import ItemCardClasses from './ItemCard.module.css';
import Button from '../../Buttons/Buttons';
import ProgressBar from "../../ProgressBars/ProgressBar/ProgressBar";
import TextItem from "./TextItem/TextItem";

interface ItemCardProps {
    doesBadge: boolean;
    //  imgSource:string;
    titleCard: string;
    btnText: string;
    progressPercentage: string;
    progressStepName: string;
    isReady: boolean;
}

const ItemCard: React.FC<ItemCardProps> = props => {

    return (
        <div className={ItemCardClasses.itemCard__container}>
            {!props.isReady ? props.doesBadge ?
                <div className={ItemCardClasses.badgeContainer}>
                    <span>بررسی تخصصی فایل</span>
                </div> : null : null
            }
            <div className={ItemCardClasses.itemCard__imageContainer}>
                <img src="/images/order-tracking/817720_check_395x512.png" alt={`${props.titleCard} image`}/>
            </div>

            <div className={ItemCardClasses.itemCard__detailsContainer}>
                <h3 className={ItemCardClasses.itemCard__header}>کارت ویزیت مربعی (ابزار طراحی آنلاین)</h3>
                {props.isReady ?
                    <>
                        <ProgressBar progressPercentage={'40%'} progressStepName={'چاپ'}/>
                        <div className={ItemCardClasses.itemCard__btnContainer}>
                            <Button isBoldText={false} btnTitle={'جزییات'} backgroundBtn={'primary'}/>
                        </div>
                    </> : <>
                        <TextItem/>
                    </>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

    );
};


export default ItemCard;
```

i'm using react with typescript and i have a problem. i want when pass isReady props into the itemcard component , itemcard component don't push me for enter progressPercentage and progressStepName and btnText props.the above code snippet show some of my components.
The order tracking component as same as index.js and app.js in react,
card component is a container for my itemscard component.

Comment: Please share reproducable example. Don't use screenshots

Comment: Screenshots suck because this is a community site, and the questions that you ask will be useful to others who face the same problem. If this information is presented in image format, it can't be searched. This means that you are less likely to attract answers from those who better understand the community nature of the site. Ask a better question: present ***ALL*** relevant information as ***TEXT*** please.

Comment: Screenshots look good. But if you provide code / text, I can copy and quickly try and write an answer.

Comment: @AjeetShah hey man i put my code i very appreciate you if take a look

Comment: @captain-yossarian ok thankyou this is my code

Comment: @spender ok i put my code